# Installing my codeigniter project on a linux box

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, odbc

So I have a codeigniter project on IIS and have cloned it on my linux dev machine. It was giving me a blank white screen which I determined was because i am using ODBC driver and didnt have php-odbc installed. I corrected that and now I get the following error:

```
Message: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found, SQL state 01000 in SQLConnect
```

I am new to the odbc driver so i very well could be missing a step in setting up besides yum install php-odbc.

PHP info:

```
odbc

ODBC Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
ODBC library => unixODBC
ODBC_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include
ODBC_LFLAGS => -L/usr/lib64
ODBC_LIBS => -lodbc

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
odbc.allow_persistent => On => On
odbc.check_persistent => On => On
odbc.default_cursortype => Static cursor => Static cursor
odbc.default_db => no value => no value
odbc.default_pw => no value => no value
odbc.default_user => no value => no value
odbc.defaultbinmode => return as is => return as is
odbc.defaultlrl => return up to 4096 bytes => return up to 4096 bytes
odbc.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
odbc.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
```

freetds.conf:

```
[CrmSqlServer]
        host = 10.1.*******
        port = 1433
        tds version = 9.0
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
[TDS]
Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
Description = FreeTDS driver
Setup = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so
```

odbc.ini:

```
[CrmSqlServer]
Driver = TDS
Description = My Server
ServerName = CrmSqlServer
Database = ******_CRM2011
```

tsql:

```
tsql -S CrmSqlServer -U mshreport
#success
```

osql / isql:

```
isql CrmSqlServer user password -v
-bash: !9: event not found
```

codeigniter config:

```
$db['sql']['hostname'] = 'DRIVER={TDS};SERVER=10.1.*******;DATABASE=**************_CRM2011;UID=username;PWD=password';
$db['sql']['username'] = 'username';
$db['sql']['password'] = 'password';
$db['sql']['database'] = '*************_CRM2011';
$db['sql']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['sql']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['sql']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['sql']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['sql']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['sql']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['sql']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['sql']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['sql']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['sql']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['sql']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

odbc error:

```
odbc_pconnect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source, SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect
```

**UPDATE:**

I have rolled my previous 3 updates into more specific information above.

Not sure if this helps or not but I am completely stuck now.

Comment: Check if it is enabled in php

Comment: Added php info information to original question

Comment: Have you seen this link? http://www.trevorbowen.com/2011/02/22/connect-to-a-microsoft-sql-server-from-linux/

Comment: I have connected to the sql server using tsql. My issue is that I am getting the above error when using the odbc driver in codeigniter 2.2.0

Comment: Are you able to connect from the same server you're running CI on?

Comment: my original server is IIS and it has no issue connecting. Neither my original server or the new linux server im trying to migrate to are on the same server as the database. On the linux server I cannot connect through codeigniter but i can through tsql (as stated in the question)

Comment: Have you tried to connect on your linux server? Are the required ports open?

Comment: Yes....as stated in the question....I have connected to the sql server from the linux box using tsql

Comment: Try changing your hostname from 'DRIVER={TDS}' to 'DRIVER=FreeTDS;DSN=CrmSqlServer'

Comment: Could you find a sollution? I stucked with the same problem here

Comment: sadly i couldn't. I ended up moving on to another job and now i work primarily with Laravel thank goodness ;)